# cannot execute matplotlib example

Tags: numpy, python-3.x, matplotlib, scipy

I installed python3.2.3 on Debian 7.1 and installed `numpy`, `scipy`, `matplotlib` with it. When I wanted to test `matplotlib` with the basic example, it didn't execute and didn't error the execution. Here is what versions I have on my machine

```
vie@w:~$ python3
Python 3.2.3 (default, Feb 20 2013, 17:02:41)
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import scipy
>>> print (scipy.__version__)
0.10.1
>>> import numpy
>>> print (numpy.__version__)
1.7.0
>>> import matplotlib
>>> print (matplotlib.__version__)
1.2.0

vie@w:~$ python3 mpl.py
vie@w:~$
```

I wanted to test the `matplotlib` (from the website http://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/basic_example.html)

Nothing happens...

When I tested this file with python 2.7, it worked.

Why cannot I execute my `mpl.py` file with python 3?

Comment: your version of scipy is rather old, the current is 0.12. Where did you install your packages from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like however you installed matplotlib for python3, the interactive backends weren't built.

There are a number of reasons this might happen.  The most likely one is that Tk wasn't available on your python3 install.

What happens when you do:

```
python3 -c 'import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; print(plt.get_backend())'
```

You should see `TkAgg` (or `GtkAgg`, `QtAgg`, etc) if you're on a machine running an X-server.  If you're seeing `Agg`, that means matplotlib wasn't built with an interactive backend, and the install will be limited to saving (but not displaying) figures.

As second test, can you run a [simple hello-world Tkinter example](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/tkinter.html#a-simple-hello-world-program) in python3?

Comment: I used your advise with python3 -c 'import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; print(plt.get_backend())' and as an outcome a got Agg. Also I ran simple hello-world Tkinter example. It worked after I installed tk and tcl. But my problem is still there. The images are not interactive. Could you, please, help me with how to build matplotlib with the interactive backend?

Comment: If you got `Agg`, you'll need to re-build matplotlib. Now that you've installed tk and tcl, it should recognize that they're there and build the `TkAgg` backend.

Comment: It worked. After I installed tk and tcl and rebuilt matplotlib. Thank you Joe for your help!!